# How to login on Amazon using Guzzle PHP

Tags: php, symfony, web-scraping, guzzle, domcrawler

I'm trying to login on Amazon using Guzzle but I'm not having luck. Here's my code:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['cookies' => true]);

$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/sign-in.html', [
    'form_params' => [
        'ap_email' => "email@gmail.com",
        'ap_password' => "12345678"
    ]
]);
```

When I get the response of it `$response->getBody()->getContents()` it returns the login page not the redirected page when successfully loged in.

Comment: Many websites prevent POSTing to their forms, especially login forms, from anywhere but the login page, e.g. through [CSRF tokens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention). You likely can't interact with Amazon this way. What is your goal?

Comment: @Chris thanks for your comment. I want to login to Amazon to be able to get email from a reviewer (Amazon now demands that you login first to see the email)

Comment: I can see Amazon check too much things. Example: appActionToken, appAction, openid.pape.max_auth_age, openid.return_to, metadata1,.....

Comment: @robot11, doesn't the email also get sent to you _via_ email? That's likely a much better place to get it, using IMAP (my preference) or POP3.

Comment: @Chris Sorry, I think I weren't clear. I want to get the email from a top reviewer. Amazon display that on it's site (https://www.amazon.com/review/top-reviewers). I want to scrape the emails from all top reviewers.

Answer (score 1):

In your case it's better to use a web **scraper**, like [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte). It emulates a user with a browser, so you don't need to worry about many things (like CSRF protection and other hidden fields).

You can use it with Guzzle as a driver, but some sites might require JavaScript (I'm not sure about Amazon). Then you have to go to a real browser or PhantomJS (a kind of headless Chrome).